# How to read txt file from ARL NOAA

Tags: python, pandas

Good evening! I will like to create a dataframe from txt file and it is on https://ready.arl.noaa.gov/readyou/174479_METGRAM.TXT. The text file is:

```
HR             
0     + 0.    13.0   3.3   51.50   0.0   97.4   0.0   0.0   7.0          
1     + 3.    21.7   4.8   33.00   0.0   90.5   0.0   0.0   4.8        
2     + 6.    30.6   0.3   14.30   0.0   57.8   0.0   0.0   3.3 
.      
.      
51   +153.    31.2  -2.3   11.3   0.00   5.1    20.1  -0.9  1.7  
52   +156.    28.5  -0.5   15.2   0.00   12.2   86.0  -4.5  1.4
```

I read data so:

df=pd.read_table('https://ready.arl.noaa.gov/readyou /174479_METGRAM.TXT',skiprows=1,sep='\s+',header=None)

```
     0     1     2       3      4       5     6      7      8      9         
0    +     0.0  13.0    3.3    51.50   0.0   97.4   0.0    0.0    7.0          
1    +     3.0  21.7    4.8    33.00   0.0   90.5   0.0    0.0    4.8        
2    +     6.0  30.6    0.3    14.30   0.0   57.8   0.0    0.0    3.3       
.          
.          
.
51  +153.  31.2  -2.3  11.3    0.00    5.1   20.1   -0.9   1.7    NaN
52  +156.  28.5  -0.5  15.2    0.00    12.2  86.0   -4.5   1.4    NaN
53  +159.  17.6   1.9  34.9    0.17    0.5  126.2  -26.3   5.6    NaN
```

i will like to get this:

```
      0      1      2       3      4       5     6      7      8               
0    +0.0  13.0    3.3    51.50   0.0    97.4   0.0    0.0    7.0          
1    +3.0  21.7    4.8    33.00   0.0    90.5   0.0    0.0    4.8        
2    +6.0  30.6    0.3    14.30   0.0    57.8   0.0    0.0    3.3       
.          
.          
.
51  +153.  31.2    -2.3    11.3   0.00   5.1    20.1  -0.9    1.7 
52  +156.  28.5    -0.5    15.2   0.00   12.2   86.0  -4.5    1.4
53  +159.  17.6     1.9    34.9   0.17   0.5   126.2  -26.3   5.6
```

how can i get this?

Comment: Please post a snippet of 174479_METGRAM.TXT. The link appears to be broken.

Comment: I have put an extract of the data

Answer (score 0):

If each column is separated by 2-or-more spaces, then you could parse the data using the [regex pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) `\s{2,}`. For example,

```
df = pd.read_table('https://ready.arl.noaa.gov/readyou /174479_METGRAM.TXT',
                   skiprows=1, sep='\s{2,}',header=None)
```

If some of the columns only have 1 space between them and yet `+ 0.` must be recognized as a single value, then you could use the regex pattern `(?<![+-])\s+`. This regex matches 1-or-more spaces *not preceeded by* a plus or minus sign. Thus a single space between numbers can be recognized as a separator, but the space between `+` and `0.` would not be considered a separator because this space is preceeded by a plus sign.

If the columns are separated by tabs, then you could specify the column separator by the regex pattern `\t+`, which matches 1-or-more tabs. The snippet you posted does not appear to use tabs as separators, but I thought I'd mention this just in case the tabs somehow got converted to spaces during the pasting process.